# Suddenly running :colorscheme breaks lightline

Tags: colorscheme, statusline, version, plugin-lightline

Suddenly, after a Vim update, I guess, when I run `:colo some_color_scheme`, the coloring of my lightline status bar is black and white, as you can see in the following screencast:

[image: asciicast]

Since I version my vimrc, I've made sure that the issue happens even if I revert to a very old version of my vimrc, where I'm sure that `:colo` was fine, becasue I often use `:so ~/.vimrc` and it has always been fine.

Anyone can reproduce it?

This is the minimal vimrc I need to reproduce it (well, not quite minimal, as I have `vim-plug` stuff in it, but ...)

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'junegunn/vim-plug'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
call plug#end()
set laststatus=2
```

This is my version of Vim:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 17 2020 21:54:53)
Included patches: 1-1704
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       +tcl/dyn
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              +perl/dyn          +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           +python/dyn        +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       +lua/dyn           +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+dnd               +mouse             +sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -pthread    -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -D_REENTRANT  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf    -lcanberra  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc   -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm
```

Comment: How recent is your vim? Latest has patches that might affect it.

Comment: @MaximKim, updated.

Comment: just a note on visible part of your vimrc, your `hi` commands would not survive colorscheme changes. Usually colorscheme tuning is done in `ColorScheme` autocommand. Do you have `hi` commands that tune your lightline?

Comment: I can reproduce it with `:colo blue` and again `:colo blue`

Comment: And it is restored once you get into insert mode and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/6970 and related https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4405

Basically, before the patch it was impossible to put vim into full "default colors mode" as there were no way to do it -- `:hi link` survived `:hi clear`. Also cleared highlight groups were impossible to set with `:hi def groupname ...`.

I guess that lightline relies on pre-patched behaviour when highlight links survived colorscheme change.

PS, has checked lightline source -- looks like it should work as it has autocommand to reapply all colors on colorscheme change...

PPS, have just installed lightline -- it works for me when I change colorschemes (vim 8.2.1728).

PPPS, add following to your vimrc:

```
augroup lightline_hl | au!
    au Colorscheme * call lightline#disable() | call lightline#enable()
augroup END
```

Comment: Ok, I will try to reduce my vimrc to the minimum so that the issue is still reproducible and add it to the question

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis could you upload your vimrc somewhere to check it?

Comment: yeah, read my comment above . I'll do it ASAP.

Comment: https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim/issues/512

Comment: have just installed vim-airline -- it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I've added my minimal vimrc. However, it seems your answer is pretty comprehensive, so I've accepted it already. Thanks for creating an issue on lightline GitHub repo.